# Errors in c++ with header files

Tags: c++

Hello I am trying to run this code with a header file

```
//#include <iostream>
//#include <cmath>
#include "formula.h"
//using namespace std;


int main()
{
//double r1;
//double r2;
//double r3;
//double combinedresistors;
//double counter;

cout << "Enter your first resistance value:";
cin >> r1;
cout << "Enter your second resistance value:";
cin >> r2;
cout << "Enter your third resistance value:";
cin >> r3;

//combinedresistors = 1/((1/r1) + (1/r2) + (1/r3));

if (r1 == 0 )
  cout << "ERROR:You can't have your resistance(s) value be zero";
//  counter = 1;
else if (r2 == 0)
  cout << "ERROR:You can't have your resistance(s) value be zero";
//  counter = 1;
else if (r3 == 0)
    cout << "ERROR:You can't have your resistance(s) value be zero";
  //  counter = 1;
else
  cout << "Your combined Resistance is:" << combinedresistors << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Here is the header file. It is called formula.h

```
  //header file
  #include <iostream>
  #include <cmath>
  #include <string>

  using namespace std;

  double combinedresistors;
  double r1;
  double r2;
  double r3;

  combinedresistors = 1/((1/r1) + (1/r2) + (1/r3));
```

I have commented out the parts in the main.cpp file because I assume I won't be needing them because they are in the header file. This is the error I am getting...

```
 c:\work area\c++\lab3\formula.h(15): error C4430: missing type specifier - 
 int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
 c:\work area\c++\lab3\formula.h(15): error C2371: 'combinedresistors': 
 redefinition; different basic types
 c:\work area\c++\lab3\formula.h(10): note: see declaration of 
 'combinedresistors'
 .\Lab3.cpp(34): error C2088: '<<': illegal for class
```

I have tried many things and looked over the internet and can't find anything about these, so I need help.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you expect `combinedresistors = 1/((1/r1) + (1/r2) + (1/r3));` to work? It's invalid syntax and none of those variables are initialized.

Comment: the r1,r2,r3 are the user inputs...this formula is a general formula to find the total resistance.

Comment: You can't put calculations outside methods/functions and writing a calculation that way doesn't make it into a function you could call in any way. In any case variable definitions in a header outside of a class is a no-no.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen so are you saying I can't have the combinedreistors formula outside of the main.cpp?

Comment: You *can* have the `combinedresistors` calculation defined outside of main.cpp, however it needs to be inside a function. Normally that function would accept the three resistor values (or a list of values in the form of a `vector` or other container) and return the result, rather than using global variables.

Comment: You can, if you put it in a function. But you can't just write calculations and assume they'll be calculated later. They're done right where it's written, with the values the variables have then.

Comment: Your error message indicates the error is on line 15 of the header, yet you show ***only 12 lines*** of the header. That aside the error message is extremely clear - **missing type specifier**!

Comment: Off topic: Placing definitions in headers leads to trouble. Including a header effectively pastes the contents of the header into the including file. This means that every file including formula.h will declare `combinedresistors` and the other variables. If you have two files in the same program including formula.h, you will have two different `combinedresistors` and when the linker tries to put these two files together into one program it finds the two `combinedresistors` and doesn't even try to figure out which one is real. It will just print an an error message and give up.

Comment: More reading on the One Definition Rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write `combinedresistors = 1/((1/r1) + (1/r2) + (1/r3));` in some function. Like,

```
double GetCombinedResistors()
{
 return 1/((1/r1) + (1/r2) + (1/r3));
}
```

And use,

```
  cout << "Your combined Resistance is:" << GetCombinedResistors() << endl;
```

Comment: Better still, make `r1`, `r2`, `r3` parameters to the function, rather than using global variables.

Comment: @DavidScarlett Agreed. At least OP should understand syntax first.

Comment: This is my error: error C4716: 'GetCombinedResistors': must return a value

Comment: @jde Correct, if you have return type, you must return value. See `GetCombinedResistors()` returns a value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a good cpp programmer but you can try with this:

```
//#include <cmath>
#include "formula.h"
//using namespace std;


int main()
{
double r1;
double r2;
double r3;
double combinedresistors;
double counter;

cout << "Enter your first resistance value:";
cin >> r1;
cout << "Enter your second resistance value:";
cin >> r2;
cout << "Enter your third resistance value:";
cin >> r3;

if (r1 == 0 || r2 == 0 || r3 == 0){
  cout << "ERROR:You can't have your resistance(s) value be zero";
}
else{
  combinedresistors = 1/((1/r1) + (1/r2) + (1/r3));
  cout << "Your combined Resistance is:" << combinedresistors << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is pretty much where OP started.